# How to test multiple scenarios different user's in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm new to JMeter. I don't know how to test different scenario with different user in jmeter. I tried multiple recording controller but only the first recorder controllers all the scenario. I just want to run all the scenarios simultaneously.

Just take an example of my test application. I have 5 different modules in my application and I want to test these 5 modules with 5 different users simultaneously.

User 1 --> Module 1

### User 2 --> Module 2

--
User 5 --> Module 5

I'm not sure whether I'm proceeding JMeter in right way or not. I just wanna know whether my scenario is possible in JMeter or not?

Thanks & Regards
Testing Team
Nayasoft

Answer (score 1):

I use different thread group for each user type. In your case, you can assume you have a different user type for each module under test,

I suggest you use a different thread group for each module.

You can later vary the number of each type of user to test the load and performance.

On the test plan, make sure the 'run consecutively' box is not checked, so all your modules are tested at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use 'If controller'. E.g. you have 5 users, so you could choose the scenario which is depend from the user or some other criteria (e.g. scenario 1 if user#1, scenario 2 if user#2...). So some certain scenario will be executed for each thread. Users could be taken from csv file.